# Can't figure out whats causing the horizontal scroll

Tags: css

On [this](https://www.demacmedia.com/) site, there is a horizontal scroll on the pages. I am unable figure out what element is causing the horizontal scroll bar to appear.

Comment: .home-quotes {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.quote-wrapper__diagonal` was rotated 3 degrees and that caused it to be longer than the page width. `.slick-track` is also longer. Hence, there are two elements that are longer than the page width.

Add `overflow: hidden` to their common parent `.home-quotes` and you should be good:

```
.home-quotes { overflow: hidden; }
```

Comment: Even if I remove that the horizontal scroll is still there and is on pages which dont have the .quotes-wrapper__diagonal div.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/1KozZ. The way to find it is pretty simple. Start deleting elements from the page in the body and see if the scrollbar disappears. The scrollbar disappeared when I deleted `.subnav` hence I could be sure that the scrollbar was appearing due to that. Then I manually inspected the elements within `.subnav`.

Comment: Thanks  for the tick. I solved the problem by adding overflow:hidden to its parent class #content. Could this be a fine way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The css width on your slick-track class is also set to six thousand-something pixels, which is wider than most screens

Comment: Even after minimizing that, the horizontal scroll doesn't get removed.